# How to extract weekly report and log from a test under execution for 60 days in Robot Framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests, performance-testing, robotframework, atdd

I am running a performance/reliability/stress(P/S/R) testing script in my SUT(system under test) using Robot Framework and some internal libraries (e.g. s2l, os, bulletin, collection, datetime and some own in-house libraries), and which need to run for 60 days to measure the expected P/S/R parameters.I know after completing its 60 days execution (if the SUT is not interrupted by any system or networking issues), i will get log and report file.
But, i have a requirement of getting its weekly execution status as log file or report file.

Is there any way to do this in Robot Framework,i am using robot framework only for my testing.Is there any internal/external libraries available (apart from bulletin library) to do this efficiently.

Or, can i include a python script and include the script in the test ENV, if so how can i do this, Any suggestions.

Comment: Is this a single test that runs for 60 days, or a smaller test that runs many times over the course of 60 days?

Comment: Its a single test that runs for 60 days

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to rewrite the test so that it runs for one week. Then, schedule a job using jenkins or a python script or bash script that runs that test eight times. This gives you the benefit of a weekly report, and at the end you can use rebot to combine all of the reports into a single larger report.

Another option would be to use the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-listener-interface) to stream test results to some other process or file. Then, once a week you can create your own report from this data. For example, you could set up an [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) server to store the results, and use [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) to view the results.

Comment: AFAIK, listener interface only notifies when test fails, but my requirement is to get report weekly, does not matter when test fails or pass. Pls correct me if i am wrong about listener interface.

Comment: @rk_12: no, the listener interface will notify you when a suite, test or keyword starts, and when it ends. You also get the status, regardless of whether it's a pass or fail. You get all of the exact same data that is in the output.xml file.